# Preemptive task scheduling in C

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, greedy

I have a list of tasks which have 3 parameters to be taken into account while scheduling: release time, duration and deadline.

**Release time** is the earliest possible start time of the task. **Duration** is the amount of time taken for the execution of the task. **Deadline** is the latest possible finish time of the task.

For example, the input is:

```
4  
2   3   5  
4   2   8  
1   2   6  
6   4   11
```

This means that there are 4 tasks, as indicated by the first line. From the next line onward, the first column is the release time, second column is duration and third column is deadline for each task.

The way to schedule these tasks would be:

```
Time    Task

1-2     3
2-5     1
5-6     3
6-8     2
8-12    4 <--- Deadline Violation
```

The goal is to write an algorithm to schedule tasks so that the number of **deadline violations is minimised**.

So, for the above case we must have an output:

```
1   2   3
2   5   1
5   6   3
6   8   2
8   12  4
```

where the first column is start times, second column is end times and third column is task number.

I think we need to use a greedy algorithm for this purpose, yet I am not entirely sure.

Therefore, I'm looking for possible algorithms/approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: We are not a service which takes business requirements and turns them into code.  You write the code, then ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: running tasks by giving priority to the task with earliest deadline will solve the problem

Comment: I'm afraid @JohnZwinck is perfectly correct.  This question is too broad for this site - you're not asking for help with code, you're asking for help choosing an algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scheduling theory, your problem can be expressed with the following notation:

```
1|r_j|sum(U_j)
```

(You can have a look at [this wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_theoretic_scheduling_problems) for more explanations on the notation)

According to [this website](http://www2.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/knust/class/dateien/classes/ein_ma/ein_ma.pdf),
 your problem is NP-hard since for example 1|r_j|L_max is NP-hard.

It means that you cannot find a greedy algorithm that will solve your problem in polynomial time (unless P=NP, which is a o[ne-million dollar open question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Reasons_to_believe_P_%E2%89%A0_NP), but no one really believes in it).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to approach the problem by means of scheduling theory with regards to exact methods. Writing a mathematical model of your problem leads to the following optimal solution.

1 3 3

3 6 1

6 8 2

8 12 4

The objective function minimizes the lateness i.e. number of "days" late. For you example there are 2 days late.